# How to regex match everything but long words?

Tags: regex

I would like to select all long words from a string: `re.findall("[a-z]{3,}")`

However, for a reason I can use substitute only. Hence I need to substitute everything but words of 3 and more letters by space. (e.g. `abc de1 fgh ij` -> `abc fgh`)

How would such a regex look like?

The result should be all "[a-z]{3,}" concatenated by spaces. However, you can use substitution only.

Or in Python: Find a `regex` such that

```
re.sub(regex, " ", text) == " ".join(re.findall("[a-z]{3,}", text))
```

Here is some test cases

```
import re
solution_regex="..."
for test_str in ["aaa aa aaa aa",
                 "aaa aa11",
                 "11aaa11 11aa11",
                 "aa aa1aa aaaa"
                ]:
    expected_str = " ".join(re.findall("[a-z]{3,}", test_str))
    print(test_str, "->", expected_str)

    if re.sub(solution_regex, " ", test_str)!=expected_str:
        print("ERROR")

->
aaa aa aaa aa -> aaa aaa
aaa aa11 -> aaa
11aaa11 11aa11 -> aaa
aa aa1aa aaaa -> aaaa
```

Note that space is no different than any other symbol.

Comment: I have understood that you mean only words without digits and at least of 3 letters. If it is correct, put it in the question, if not, put your correct requirements there.

Comment: Yes, words are defined as in the first line of the question. I added a Python expression to make it more clear.

Comment: :-) You have forgotten to mention the language in tags. Also, if you are seraching for a correct regex, do not use regex for definition. Are you asking us to correctly set the task? Use words for definition, please, please!

Comment: "to substitute everything but words of 3 and more letters by space" Please, what do you want to substitute?

Comment: In ,256#,AA,1BBBBBB, what will match?

Comment: @Gangnus: Everything that is _un_selected in https://regex101.com/r/4vQPw8/1 should match (I actually also want uppercase). Hence `,256#,AA,1` and `,` should match.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\b(?:[a-z,A-Z,_]{1,2}|\w*\d+\w*)\b
```

Explanation:

- `\b` means that the substring you are looking for start and end by `border of word`
- `(?:  )` - non captured group
- `\w*\d+\w*` Any word that contains at least one digit and consists of digits, '_' and letters

[Here](https://regex101.com/r/iGJt8c/3) you can see the test.

Comment: This does not _substitute everything but words_. I basically I want to select and substitute the exact negation of this.

Comment: "I would like to select all long words" - it is the first line of your question! Please, edit it!

Comment: Looks good. It would be slightly more convenient, if it would collapse to only one consecutive space in the result. Is there a simple fix?

Comment: Oh, and you treat digits separately? Actually I only have of notion of letter or non-letter. So digits shouldnt be different from spaces in the treatment.

Comment: @Toto Yes. Thank you very much. And '_' was forgotten, too.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the regex

> (\s\b(\d*[a-z]\d*){1,2}\b)|(\s\b\d+\b)

and replace with an empty string, here is a python code for the same

```
import re

regex = r"(\s\b(\d*[a-z]\d*){1,2}\b)|(\s\b\d+\b)"

test_str = "abcd abc ad1r ab a11b a1 11a 1111 1111abcd a1b2c3d"

subst = ""

# You can manually specify the number of replacements by changing the 4th argument
result = re.sub(regex, subst, test_str, 0)

if result:
    print (result)
```

here is a [demo](https://regex101.com/r/X3B12a/3)

Comment: You take a1a, but refuse a11a. Why? Your "large" words include a1, that is NOT large, according to the question

Comment: Thanks for correcting my answer, could you take a look at the updated demo ?

Comment: By words I consider any substring if 3 or more letters. I updated the question to make it better defined. In this version you get incorrect results if digits are before or after words. Also digits at the start cause trouble. Even with the corrected version.

Comment: Could you give me a valid long number which has digits in them ?

Comment: Any string could be input, and only the result is important. For example with `abcd abc8 ad1r ab a11b a1 11a ` the `8` makes `abc` disappear. Ideally the there also should be only one space between each long word.

Comment: Not quite. Effectively,I want to select precisely every character which `[a-z]{3,}` does *not* select. A bit like https://regex101.com/r/mUtFC5/1 but that doesn't select the spaces and has more corner cases which don't work :/

Comment: [a-z]{3,} won't select a1b2c3d, is that expected ?

Comment: I have updated the answer, this would replace any string that does not have 3 charactes between a-z in them, and handles the space

Comment: You don't match AD

Comment: AD, you mean to say uppercase letters ?

Answer (score 0):

In Autoit this works for me

```
#include <Array.au3>
$a = StringRegExp('abc de1 fgh ij 234234324 sdfsdfsdf wfwfwe', '(?i)[a-z]{3,}', 3)
ConsoleWrite(_ArrayToString($a, ' ') & @CRLF)
```

Result ==> abc fgh sdfsdfsdf wfwfwe

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

regex = r"(?:^|\s)[^a-z\s]*[a-z]{0,2}[^a-z\s]*(?:\s|$)"
str = "abc de1 fgh ij"
subst = " "

result = re.sub(regex, subst, str)
print (result)
```

**Output:**

```
abc fgh
```

**Explanation:**

```
(?:^|\s)    : non capture group, start of string or space
[^a-z\s]*   : 0 or more any character that is not letter or space
[a-z]{0,2}  : 0, 1 or 2  letters
[^a-z\s]*   : 0 or more any character that is not letter or space
(?:\s|$)    : non capture group, space or end of string
```

Comment: 1. use \\b. It is much more simple. 2. [^a-z\s] is any character that is not a space or a SMALL letter. So, a single large letter in the string will forbid to find any word.

Comment: Introducing digits here and there gives incorrect results. I updated the question to make the expectation better defined.

Comment: @Gangnus: `\b` is not applicable because `de1` must be removed. For second point, it is easy to add a case insensitive.

Comment: @Gerenuk: Please, add some test cases in your question.

Comment: Test cases added

Answer (score 0):

With the other ideas posted here, I came up with an answer. I can't believe I missed that:

```
([^a-z]+|(?<![a-z])[a-z]{1,2}(?![a-z]))+
```

https://regex101.com/r/IIxkki/2

Match either non-letters, or up to two letters bounded by non-letters.